# What does ' My stomach turned to water mean '?

Tags: meaning

I found this phrase in *To Kill a Mockingbird*, but I am not sure what it means. I understand it is a metaphor. But what is the speaker trying to say here?

Answer (score 1):

It means essentially the same as "butterflies in your stomach", when you're anxious about something.

Comment: OED **collywobbles** *- a disordered state of the stomach characterized by rumbling in the intestines; diarrhœa with stomach-ache; hence gen. indisposition, ‘butterflies in the stomach’, a state of nervous fear.*